# Object composition: storing references vs. IDs of references

Tags: object, memory-management, rust

Back with another noob question about fundamental design decisions in Rust.

I'm writing a simple little game. I have a pool of game objects in a datastructure keyed by their "id". My question is how to handle other structs (shorter-lived than the ones in the pool) which have a relation to objects in the pool.

At first I did the following:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
  game_obj: &'a GameObject
  // etc.
}
```

But then I ran into a bunch of issues with the borrow checker when trying to refer (mutably) to the `GameObject` in the same scope as an extant `Foo`.

So now I'm considering something like:

```
struct Foo {
  game_obj_id: uint,
  // etc.
}
```

This probably has other issues, but it does solve the immediate one of `Foo` "monopolizing" the ability to reference its related `GameObject`.

What are some usual approaches to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a `Rc<RefCell<GameObject>>` in your `struct` instead (unless `GameObject` is a trait, in which case this will not work until dynamically sized types (DST) are implemented).

[`RefCell<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) is a type that contains a `T` and a flag that indicates whether the value has been borrowed mutably, has been borrowed immutably or has not been borrowed. `RefCell` basically moves the borrow checking at runtime rather than at compile time; if the borrow rules are violated (can't make a mutable borrow if it has already been borrowed mutably or immutably; can't make an immutable borrow if it has already been borrowed mutably), the task will fail. Note that there can be multiple immutable borrows at the same time.

[`Rc<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) is a type that contains a pointer to a `T` and a reference count (two actually: a strong reference count and a weak reference count). You can `.clone()` an `Rc` to increase the reference count without cloning the underlying object. When an `Rc` is dropped, the reference count is decremented. When the reference count drops to zero, the referent is dropped and the memory is reclaimed. Note that `Rc` already allocates memory dynamically; there's no need to use constructs such as `Rc<Box<Thing>>` (unless you know what you're doing).

There's also [`Weak<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html), which can be used instead of `Rc` for references that don't need to keep the object alive.

Comment: would this require also changing the GameObject pool? Or can I keep that as [GameObject, ..COUNT]?

Comment: The `GameObject` is stored inside the `RefCell`, so you'd have to make an array of `RefCell<GameObject>`. However, instead of using `Rc`, you may be able to use a simple borrowed pointer to the `RefCell`.

Comment: it took me a couple days of screwing around to understand this and get this working, but I finally have something that both compiles and runs :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm also curious about Weak<T>... it seems quite hard to use? I ended up just using plain Rc, because it seemed like in order to actually DO anything at all with the Weak rc, I had to upgrade() it to a normal one anyway...

Comment: You'll want to use `Weak<T>` in long-lived data structures to allow the referenced object to be dropped if it's no longer needed. When you're about to use it, you must `upgrade()` it to a `Rc<T>` to ensure that the object isn't dropped while you're using it. However, `upgrade()` will return `None` if the object has already been dropped.